# How to find magazines in News+?

Tags: macos, ios, news.app, apple-news

For example, is there a way to search whether

```
Businessweek
今周刊
```

is in News+? I was later able to find Businessweek, find have to scroll alphabetically among A to Z and it was under Bloomberg Businessweek.  So if it is alphabetically, it'd be hard to find Bicycle if the title is "Rides and Bicycles".

Comment: You want to search for the title of a magazine?

Comment: yes... that's one common way how people search for books or magazines